# Can't import .gif file into python turtle library

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Trying to import some shapes into a simple code but getting the error:
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "tess.gif": no such file or directory

edit: everything is in the same folder

```
Kal = turtle.Turtle()
Arrow = turtle.Turtle()
Turtlebutton = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.register_shape("tess.gif")
turtle.register_shape("btnTurtle.gif")

Kal.shape("turtle")

Monitor =turtle.Screen()
Monitor.setup(800, 600)

def Switcharrow(x,y):
    Kal.shape("arrow")

def Switchturtle(x,y):
    Kal.shape("turtle")

Arrow.hideturtle()
Arrow.shape("btnArrow.gif")
Arrow.penup()
Arrow.goto(-315,260)
Arrow.onclick(Switcharrow)
Arrow.showturtle()

Monitor.mainloop()
```

Comment: That means the tess and btnTurtle.gif files are not located in the current working directory

Comment: @Alexander everything is located in the same folder, is there something else i have to do to get it to mingle?

Comment: your terminal needs to rooted in the same folder as well then.

Comment: @Alexander how can one do that? using visual studio if it helps

Comment: how do you execute your program?

Comment: @Alexander using the "run code" button in VS

Comment: See my answer... Ive never used Visual studio before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to change your current working directory to the folder containing your python script and image files or change your code to use paths relative to the script instead of relative to the CWD

For example:

```
import os  



def imgpath(imgname):  # this function will convert translate the paths
    parent = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    os.path.join(parent, imgname)


Kal = turtle.Turtle()
Arrow = turtle.Turtle()
Turtlebutton = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.register_shape(imgpath("tess.gif"))  # call the function on each
turtle.register_shape(imgpath("btnTurtle.gif"))  # of the img file names

Kal.shape("turtle")

Monitor =turtle.Screen()
Monitor.setup(800, 600)

def Switcharrow(x,y):
    Kal.shape("arrow")

def Switchturtle(x,y):
    Kal.shape("turtle")

Arrow.hideturtle()
Arrow.shape(imgpath("btnArrow.gif"))  # here too
Arrow.penup()
Arrow.goto(-315,260)
Arrow.onclick(Switcharrow)
Arrow.showturtle()

Monitor.mainloop()
```